# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'xxx' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have declared a variable & appended strings with comma separated. This variable i want to use for a where condition for another query.

```
declare @AllIDs varchar(max)
set @AllIDs = ''

select 
    @AllIDs = (@AllIDs + cast(ID as varchar(10)) + ',') 
from EmployeeDetail WHERE Code In(
'ABC1','ABC2'
)

select @AllIDs

select * from TBL_OT where EmployeeId In(@AllIDs)
```

The EmployeeId is of type int. so it is giving me error :-

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'xxx' to data type
>   int.

Comment: You can only do this with dynamic SQL. Your query will evaluate to `in('x, y')`, when you need `in('x', 'y')`.

Comment: If you want use the IN Operator for a variable. You have make use of a dynamic query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use DynamicSQL:

```
declare @AllIDs nvarchar(max)
set @AllIDs = '('

select 
    @AllIDs = (@AllIDs + cast(ID as nvarchar(10)) + ',') 
from EmployeeDetail WHERE Code like 'ABC%'

set @AllIDs = @AllIDs + '-555)'

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ' select * from Tbl_OT where EmployeeId In ' + @ALLIDs + ' AND OTDate = ''2016-11-06'''

print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql,N''
```

The -555 as the last ID in the list is there to add to the last comma which otherwise will break syntax. Use some non-existing ID there.